# Java code to improvisation

Tags: java

I have to write the code based on the below criteria.

```
+-------------------------+
|A     |B     | Action    |
|null  |null  | no update |
|null  |empty | no update |
|empty |null  | no update |
|empty |empty | no update |
+-------------------------+
```

other cases can update

```
if(a == null){
    if(b == null){
        if(!(a == null  && b == null )){
            perform update;
        }
    }       
    else if(b != null){
        if(!(a == null && b.isEmpty())){
            perform update;
        }
    }
}    
else if(a.isEmpty()){
    if(b == null){
        if(!(a.isEmpty() && b == null)){
            perform update;
        }
    }       
    else if(b != null){
        if(!(a.isEmpty() && b.isEmpty())){
            perform update;
        }
    }
}    
else{
    perform update;
}
```

I thought of above solution. Is there any other solutions are there to improvise the above code?

Comment: Please ask this at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you. I don't aware of that.

Comment: @thalupulamma Nonetheless: maybe the answer you got here will do. So please dont forget about accept or maybe upvoting content over here; now that you reached upvote level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to write two little helpers:

```
boolean isNullOrEmpty(Whatever x) {
  return (x == null || x.isEmpty());
}
```

And then your code boils down to:

```
if (isNullOrEmpty(a) && isNullOrEmpty(b)) {
  return;
}

perform update
```

Should do it. The real answer here: as soon as you start **repeating** the same code (and even fragments of code) it is time to step back and search for the common patterns; so that you can extract those into distinct methods. And as the comment points out: various libraries such as Google Guava or Apache Commons might already have such helper methods.

Comment: or simply use apache commons-lang which already implement this methods

Answer (score 2):

Use `Or`

```
if(!(a == null || b == null || a.isEmpty() || b.isEmpty())) {
    update;
}
```

Or `And`

```
if(a != null && b != null && !a.isEmpty() && !b.isEmpty()) {
    update;
}
```